# Is Callback become closures?

Tags: node.js, callback, closures

```
function fn(args){
    var a= 'something';
    doSomething('dummy',function(){

    });
}

fn();
```

In this code, is anonymous callback become closure or just exit after execution? If it become become a closure, how can i get back memory because it always has access to `fn`'s activation object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only be a closure if the lambda uses the enclosing functions'(`fn`) local variables or parameter, e.g. `a` or `args`.

Re: Memory recovery - Don't worry about it* - the GC will know when references are no longer reachable and collect them (whether they are used in closures or not). [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331480/node-js-garbage-collector).

[<sub>* Don't worry too much</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19550253/314291)

Comment: If i use `fn` local variables or `arguments`, it will be closure.So, i m creating closure every time when i call `fn` & how can I clean the scope after callback was execute to get back memory.