# Does Chrome's javascript garbage collection work differently?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, v8

When I try to debug this code (http://jsfiddle.net/QWFGN/)

```
var foo = (function(numb) {
    return {
        bar: function() {
            debugger;
            return "something";
        }
    }
})(1);
foo.bar()
```

Developer tool in Chrome behaves differently than and Firebug in Firefox and developer tool in IE. The issue is that variable `numb` **is not visible in Chrome developer tool** on the `debugger;` line. But, it is visible in Firebug and IE. If I try to type `numb` in Chrome's console I get:

```
ReferenceError: numb is not defined
```

`numb`, of course, is visible in this closure, and if I change code to (http://jsfiddle.net/QWFGN/1/)

```
var foo = (function(numb) {
    return {
        bar: function() {
            debugger;
            console.log(numb);
            return "something";
        }
    }
})(1);
foo.bar()
```

`numb` is now visible in Chrome as well and I can get value `1` as a response.

So, My question is: **Why only Google Chrome doesn't see closure variables that are never used?** Does Google Chrome have it's own implementation of Garbage Collection, or is it only related to implementation of debug tool in Google Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About closure, LexicalEnvironment and GC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665781/about-closure-lexicalenvironment-and-gc) or [How are closures and scopes represented at run time in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368048/how-are-closures-and-scopes-represented-at-run-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with garbage collection or the debug tools.

What's actually happening is that Chrome's JS engine realizes that you never use `numb` inside the function, so it doesn't include it in the closure at all.

Note that it can only do this if it can prove that the inner function never uses `with` or calls `eval`.

Comment: Hi, beg your pardon for asking, but could you add a link to some official source about this? It would be great!

Comment: Obviously @SLaks is right, it is hard to pin point this in V8 documentation. Similar discussion coming to same conclusion -> http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.v8.general/678

Comment: Thx for answer. Here are some references I have found: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-2-lexical-environments-ecmascript-implementation/#codeevalcode-and-inner-functions-may-break-optimizations, https://twitter.com/erikcorry/status/53901976865476608. If someone finds link to V8 documentation where this is specified, I would really appreciate.

Comment: @dugokontov there is no documentation for this, as this is an implementation detail. You can read scope allocation code to see what really happens: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/scopes.cc?r=13781#1179