# Will JavaScript Closure save all variables in its scope, or only those the closure referred?

Tags: javascript, closures

We knew that

```
function foo () {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 20;
  function bar () {
    return x + 1;
  }
  bar(); // 11
}
```

The function `bar` create a closure, and save the reference of `x`.

But what about the variable `y`? Will the closure `bar` created hold its reference? I tried it in Chrome Dev Tools, and it shows only `x` in the `[[Scopes]]` field, without `y`. But I can not find any articles about that.

Does it means the closure creation will only pick what it need to save?

Comment: Are you asking about what should happen according to the specification or how different engines implement closures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325223/over-how-much-of-its-enclosing-scope-does-a-javascript-closure-close

Comment: Why would `bar` hold a reference to `y`?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Close as duplicate?

Comment: Note that in the code shown there is no reference to `bar()` outside of `foo()`, so the closure concept isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are chained together and it'll check with parent scope when reference cannot be find.  This question is answered before and you can reference it here:
[Scope Chain in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript)