# Does this pattern causes a circular reference in a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, circular-reference

I'm a javascript newbie. I'm recently learning javascript and its great property closure.

But I'm confused by following code snippet.

```
function outerFn() {
  var outerVar = {};
  function innerFn() {
    alert('haha');
  }
  outerVar.pro = innerFn;
  return innerFn;
}
```

I think it is not a circular reference between innerFn and outerVar, because only outerVar pro points to the innerFn.

But some book points out that it is still a circular reference.

Could anyone explain whether it is a circular reference or not?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `outerVar` is not used

Comment: For me it isn't. I think outerVar does not exist once the outerFn function ends, as it is a local variable that is not used in innerFn... actually for me this is not a closure example.

Comment: this seems to be just an private method declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **could** cause a circular reference within the JavaScript *engine* (because the parent lexical environment of `innerFn` includes `outerVal`, which includes `innerFn`), but it **does not** cause a circular reference that can be observed by JavaScript code.

When `outerFn` runs, the function `innerFn` is defined. In JavaScript, a newly-defined function has access to all variables currently accessible in scope, so code inside of `innerFn` can access `outerVar`:

```
function outerFn() {
  var outerVar = {};
  function innerFn() {
    alert(outerVar);    // totally fine
  }
  return innerFn;
}
```

In ECMAScript terms, this is achieved because every function has a *lexical environment* used to resolve variable identifiers called `[[Scope]]`. A newly-defined function's `[[Scope]]` internal property is set to the lexical environment of its parent function. So, here, the `[[Scope]]` of `innerFn` is the lexical environment of `outerFn`, which contains a reference to `outerFn`.

In ECMAScript terms, the circular reference path goes:

> - `innerFn`
> - `innerFn`'s [`[[Scope]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) (a [lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2))
> - `innerFn`'s `[[Scope]]`'s [environment record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1)
> - the `outerVar` binding in `innerFn`'s `[[Scope]]`'s environment record
> - the variable associated with the `outerVar` binding in `innerFn`'s `[[Scope]]`'s environment record
> - this variable has `innerFn` as a property value

However, since you can't access a function's `[[Scope]]` internal property from JavaScript code, you can't observe a circular reference from the code.

### Bonus info

Note that a clever implementation will not *actually* store this circular reference in your code, because it sees that `outerVar` is never used in any of `outerFn`'s child functions. The binding for `outerVar` can be safely forgotten entirely when `outerFn` ends. It is further interesting to note that this optimization is not possible with `eval`, because it's not possible to recognize whether `innerFn` will ever use `outerVar`:

```
function outerFn() {
  var outerVar = {};
  function innerFn(codeStr) {
    alert(eval(codeStr));    // will `codeStr` ever be "outerVar"?
  }
  return innerFn;
}
```

Comment: Related information on possible optimisations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8667141/1048572