# Javascript function syntax with tripple =>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

Below is a code snippet which I came across in one of the blog for redux.

[image]

This snippet explains redux-thunk. But I am trying to make sense out of the weird syntax

`return ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action =>{}`

I tried a google search with this syntax but did not get much help. I am not understanding how `next` and `action` objects are getting their values. Can someone please help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript

may be this will help.

Comment: `... => ...` is always the definition of a function which takes some parameter(s) and returns something. This just happens a few times in a row here. You have a function that returns a function that takes two parameters that returns a function that takes one parameter that returns a function that takes one parameter that returns the result of a call to `action` or perhaps `next`.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining of functions in this way is usually to enable a user to bind arguments to a final function in a controlled fashion, rather than having to supply them all in one go.

In effect it is an API design choice for a piece of functionality.

```
({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {}
```

...is equivalent to:

```
function({dispatch, getState}) { // destructure two properties into arguments
    return function(next) {
        return function(action) {
            // this function has access to `dispatch`, `getState`, `next` & `action`
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the "binding" of the arguments to the inner functions occurs through a feature of JavaScript called closures. Full explanation of closures in JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802718/closures-and-es2015).