# Javascript Cycle reference Example

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a simple question about cycles references in javascript.

Is this a cycle reference?

```
var theThing=null;

theThing = {
longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
someMethod: function () {
  console.log(someMessage);
}
```

someMethod context captures theThing variable right?

Example 2:

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
var originalThing = theThing;

theThing = {
longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
someMethod: function () {
  console.log(someMessage);
}
};
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

In example 2, is there an cycle reference? SomeMethod references originalThing which is the Thing.

Comment: yes. but it is not called a cycle reference. the someMethod method has access to theThing variable. it´s just scope.

Comment: `someMethod` does not reference anything, in this example

Comment: @Attersson updated my question

Comment: @Luke updated my question

Comment: no, your updated example 2 does NOT reference orginalThing. It only references someMessage, which is not defined, therefore it throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In example 1, someMethod context captures theThing variable right?

It [could capture it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30252621/1048572) but [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8665781/1048572) - you reference `someMessage` in the `console.log` call not `theThing`. But since both are global variables, they're closed over by the function anyway.

> In example 2, is there an cycle reference? SomeMethod references originalThing which is the Thing.

Again, no, `someMethod` only closes over `someMessage` (and `console`). `replaceThing` captures `theThing`, though, that's a genuine example of a closure. Nothing references `originalThing`, that's a local variable which is initialised but then used nowhere and will get thrown away as soon as possible.

There's no specific cyclic reference other than the basic global environment referencing `thingThing` referencing `someMethod` closing over the global environment.

> I have a simple question about [memory-leaks]

Nothing in here constitutes a memory leak.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/ Section 4 Closures. "Even though unused is never used, someMethod can be used through theThing. And as someMethod shares the closure scope with unused". Because someMethod doesnt actually use the unsed or in this case the originalThing  doesnt mean that it does not reference it.

Comment: @Nick in the example in your question, there is no `unused`, and nothing refers to `originalThing`.

Comment: @Berg- If we would put the originalThing inside someMethod then would it be a cycle reference?

Comment: @Nick No, why would that be a cyclic reference? It's a chain of large objects referencing each other without being actually used, so it probably creates a memory leak, but no cycle.

Comment: @Bergi- Ok i have 2 last questions. In the link i provided, in the closures section. No one is refering to unused, so why is there a leak? And my second question: In section Forgotten timers or callbacks (second example) why this is a cycle reference?. Thank you

Comment: @Nick "*No one is referring to unused, so why is there a leak?*" - Because of a compiler bug. (In detail: because `unused` and `someMethod` (potentially) close over the same variables, the compiler creates a variable frame that contains all variables referenced in any closure regardless of the closure's usage, leading to `someMethod` keeping the `originalThing` alive). "*In second example of "Forgotten timers or callbacks" why this is a cycle reference?*" - because the `element` references the `onclick` callback that was installed on it, and the callback closes over the `element` variable.

Comment: @Nick No idea, I'd need to search using the hints given in the article you linked. Maybe they didn't even report the issue, it's just how V8 works - see the link in my answer about GC of closures.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Scope?

If you call `theTing.someMethod()`, then `theThing` is in scope and accessable in the method.

Furthermore, there is no someMethod context. When we talk about context in JavaScript, we refer to `this`. And within `theThing.someMethod` you have indeed access to the context (`this`) of `theThing`.

```js
var foo = "bar";

var obj = {
    name: "Lukas",
    method: function() {
        // scoped foo variable
        console.log(foo);
        // scoped obj variable
        console.log(obj.name);
        // context
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

obj.method();
```

Comment: The `theThing` variable is always in scope, regardless how you call the function. If you meant the `this` value of the call, that's not "scope".

Comment: please can you tell me where I said, that depending how you call the function, the scope is different? And also, where did I say that "this" is scope? I said `this` is context :)

Comment: "*If you call `theTing.someMethod()`, then `theThing` …*" sounded to me like it depended on how it was called. Regarding the `this` keyword, sorry I didn't read your post carefully enough, looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, but if he would copy the someMethod function to a completly different place, it would still have theThing scoped, no matter what. I was just saying, that the var "theThing", as it is hoisted, wiill be available in the scope.