# Javascript: Are closures created for all variables, or only for the ones the inner function might use?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var foo = 'outer';
function outer() {
    var foo = 'closure';
    var bar = 'baz';
    return function inner() {
        console.log(foo);
    }   
}
```

I understand that `foo` will be closed over, because `inner()` will need it.

But will `bar` be closed over also? It's in `inner()`'s scope, but it isn't being used by `inner()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the whole parent scope is closed over, including the variables `foo` and `bar` and the reference to its parent scope: the function `inner` *might* need it. At least that's how it is specced. In practise, engines are free to optimise this and garbage-collect everything that is not referenced - for example, [V8 does this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5326300/1048572).

Comment: Just the parent scope? It seems that "all variables that are in scope at the point of inner's declaration are available in the closure" (paraphrased from Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja

Comment: @AdamZerner: There is a chain of scopes, each one has a reference to its parent scope. A closure scope can (will) be shared amongst all functions defined in it. "*all variables in scope*" refers to the current scope variables, and all other variables accessible from there.

Answer (score 1):

The particular variable alone will not be carry forwarded. The *whole scope* will be carry forwarded when a closure is created. In this case `foo` and `bar` and whatever variables present in that scope will be available in `inner` function.

Comment: Ok thanks. So is it just the direct parent scope that's carried forward, or is it all parent scopes? And do other languages implement this differently? It seems excessive to carry the whole scope forward when you only need parts of it.

Comment: @AdamZerner the scope of the variable which you're using in the inner function will be carry forwarded

Comment: Ah ok. So since `foo` is used in `inner`, and since `foo`'s scope is `outer`, `outer` will be carried forward in `inner`?

Comment: yup. You could say so @AdamZerner

Comment: Actually it seems that "all variables that are in scope at the point of `inner`'s declaration are available in the closure" (paraphrased from Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja