# Do ES6 arrow functions still close over "this" even if they don't use it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm trying to understand the rules of when `this` is lexically bound in an ES6 arrow function. Let's first look at this:

```
function Foo(other) {
    other.callback = () => { this.bar(); };

    this.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar called');
    };
}
```

When I construct a `new Foo(other)`, a callback is set on that other object. The callback is an arrow function, and the `this` in the arrow function is lexically bound to the `Foo` instance, so the `Foo` won't be garbage collected even if I don't keep any other reference to the `Foo` around.

What happens if I do this instead?

```
function Foo(other) {
    other.callback = () => { };
}
```

Now I set the callback to a nop, and I never mention `this` in it. **My question is:** does the arrow function still lexically bind to `this`, keeping the `Foo` alive as long as `other` is alive, or may the `Foo` be garbage collected in this situation?

Comment: Given you don't reference `this`, I doubt that the JS engine would keep a reference to the `Foo` instance, however I don't have any proof for it.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on which engine runs this code? Or is garbage collection behaviour in the specs?

Comment: I guess,  it just acting like a closure. `function test(){ var x = 10; return function(){ console.log(x); } }`

Comment: I'd recommend `()=>{ this; }`just mentioning this, doesn't have to do anything, if you want to take care this instance still sticks around. But why would you want that? Why would you want this instance to stay, if there's no other reference around so you (or any other part of your code) can access/use it?

Comment: @Thomas: Actually, I want the opposite: I want to make sure that such functions don't keep a garbage `Foo` around, and I don't know if I can rely on the JS engine to do the right thing or if I should use standard anonymous functions instead.

Comment: @cfh "I want to make sure that such functions don't keep a garbage" --- you cannot by 2 reasons: 1. the standard does not require to only capture the variables that are actually referenced. 2. the standard does not define the "garbage" term at all. Both statements are valid for both old-style anonymous functions or the fat-arrow based ones.

Comment: Closely related: [garbage collection for closed-over variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326300/garbage-collection-with-node-js)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> **My question is:** does the arrow function still lexically bind to this, keeping the Foo alive as long as other is alive, or may the Foo be garbage collected in this situation?

As far as the specification is concerned, the arrow function has a reference to the environment object where it was created, and that environment object has `this`, and that `this` refers to the `Foo` instance created by that call. So any code relying on that `Foo` not being kept in memory is relying on optimization, not specified behavior.

Re optimization, it comes down to whether the JavaScript engine you're using optimizes closures, and whether it can optimize the closure in the specific situation. (A number of things can prevent it.) The situation just like this ES5 example with a traditional function:

```
function Foo(other) {
    var t = this;
    other.callback = function() { };
}
```

In that situation, the function closes over the context containing `t`, and so in theory, has a reference to `t` which in turn keeps the `Foo` instance in memory.

That's the theory, but in practice a modern JavaScript engine can see that `t` is not used by the closure and can optimize it away provided doing so doesn't introduce an observable side-effect. Whether it does and, if so, when, is entirely down to the engine.

Since arrow functions truly are lexical closures, the situations are exactly analogous and so you'd expect the JavaScript engine to do the same thing: Optimize it away unless it causes a side-effect that can be observed. That said, remember that arrow functions are **very new**, so it may well be that engines don't have much optimization around this yet *(no pun)*.

In this particular situation, the version of V8 I was using when I wrote this answer in March 2016 (in Chrome v48.0.2564.116 64-bit) and still here in January 2021 (Brave v1.19.86 based on Chromium v88.0.4324.96) **does** optimize the closure. If I run this:

```js
"use strict";
function Foo(other) {
    other.callback = () => this; // <== Note the use of `this` as the return value
}
let a = [];
for (let n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
    a[n] = {};
    new Foo(a[n]);
}
// Let's keep a Foo just to make it easy to find in the heap snapshot
let f = new Foo({});

log("Done, check the heap");
function log(msg) {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

and then in devtools take a heap snapshot, I see the expected 10,001 instances of `Foo` in memory. If I run garbage collection (these days you can use the trash can icon; with earlier versions I had to run with a special flag and then call a `gc()` function), I still see the 10,001 `Foo` instances:

[image]

But if I change the the callback so it didn't reference `this`:

```
      other.callback = () => {  }; // <== No more `this`
```

```js
"use strict";

function Foo(other) {
    other.callback = () => {}; // <== No more `this`
}
let a = [];
for (let n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
    a[n] = {};
    new Foo(a[n]);
}
// Let's keep a Foo just to make it easy to find in the heap snapshot
let f = new Foo({});

log("Done, check the heap");
function log(msg) {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

and run the page again, I don't even have to force garbage collection, there's just the one `Foo` instance in memory (the one I put there to make it easy to find in the snapshot):

[image]

I wondered if it were the fact that the callback is *completely* empty that allowed the optimization, and was pleasantly surprised to find that it wasn't: Chrome is happy to retain parts of the closure while letting go of `this`, as demonstrated here:

```js
"use strict";
function Foo(other, x) {
    other.callback = () => x * 2;
}
let a = [];
for (let n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
    a[n] = {};
    new Foo(a[n], n);
}
// Let's keep a Foo just to make it easy to find in the heap snapshot
let f = new Foo({}, 0);
document.getElementById("btn-call").onclick = function() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    log(`a[${r}].callback(): ${a[r].callback()}`);
};
log("Done, click the button to use the callbacks");

function log(msg) {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn-call" value="Call random callback">
```

Despite the fact that the callbacks are there and have their reference to `x`, Chrome optimizes the `Foo` instance away.

---

You asked about spec references for how `this` is resolved in arrow functions: The mechanism is spread throughout the spec. Each [environment](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records) (such as the environment created by calling a function) has a `[[thisBindingStatus]]` internal slot, which is `"lexical"` for arrow functions. When determining the value of `this`, the internal operation [`ResolveThisBinding`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-resolvethisbinding) is used, which uses the internal [`GetThisEnviroment`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-getthisenvironment) operation to find the environment that has `this` defined. When a "normal" function call is made, [`BindThisValue`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-bindthisvalue) is used to bind the `this` for the function call if the environment is not a `"lexical"` environment. So we can see that resolving `this` from within an arrow function is just like resolving a variable: The current environment is checked for a `this` binding and, not finding one (because no `this` is bound when calling an arrow function), it goes to the containing environment.

Comment: That would be the expectation, but since `this` is in some sense magic, I was wondering if the exact same rules as for normal closures apply. (I didn't downvote this, ftr.)

Comment: @cfh: `this` isn't magic. :-) The specification is clear about exactly how `this` works, including how arrow functions close over it. The mechanism is exactly the same as for other variables in the context.

Comment: That's good to know. Could you provide a reference to the relevant part of the spec?

Comment: @cfh: It's all over, and the spec is very hard to read, but I've added some relevant sections above.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good theoretical answer based on the spec. Unfortunately, it seems my question can't be fully answered in general since what exactly is closed over is implementation defined.

Comment: And just as I wrote that, you added some tests! The difference to @georg's results is interesting.

Comment: @cfh: What's *closed over* isn't implementation-defined, but *is* implementation-optimized. :-)

Comment: That seems like nit picking; if the closure over some variable is optimized away because it's not used, can't we say that the variable is not closed over? My terminology may be off here because I'm not familiar with the spec.

Comment: @cfh: Yes, definitely nit-picking, sorry. I kinda meant to convey that with the smile at the end, didn't come off apparently. :-)

Comment: This is the very model of a SO answer, thanks for your efforts. Accepting this now.

Comment: I will mention that, after playing around with my actual app in the heap profiler, it did _seem_ that certain empty callbacks still retained a `this` closure which prevented collection (same Chrome version as you). So, as you said, there seem to be circumstances which break this optimization, though I have no idea what they might be.