# MeteorJS - Differences between function() and () =>

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

Right now in my helper is using `function()`

```
updateCVId: function() {
    return this._id; //return the real id

}
```

It's working, but if I use `()=>`

```
updateCVId:()=> {
    return this._id; //return undefined
}
```

then this._id is undefined.

The same is for the events:

```
'click .foo': function(evt, tmp) {
    console.log(this._id); //log the real id
}
```

and

```
'click .foo': (evt, tmp)=> {
    console.log(this._id); //log undefined
}
```

Can someone tell me if I use `()=>` , how to get the data?

Thank you guys.

Comment: In arrow functions, *this* is assigned as the *this* of the execution context in which the function is created. In a function declaration or expression, it's set by the call (or *bind*) so likely a different object.

Comment: Ok, then how to get the data in arrow function as I take it with this in the normal function?

Comment: Use a function declaration or expression (the first example), see [*Do ES6 arrow functions always close over “this”?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813344/do-es6-arrow-functions-always-close-over-this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions `=>` are designed to automatically bind the context `this` from lexical scope. In your situation `this` is undefined, because it runs in `'strict mode'`.

To solve your problem you can:

*1) Use a regular function, as you did already:*

```
var actions = {
   //...
   updateCVId: function() {
      return this._id; //return the real id
   }
   //...
};
```

*2) Use an ES6 shorthand function notation:*

```
var actions = {
   //...
   updateCVId() {
      return this._id; //return the real id
   }
   //...
};
```

---

The difference between `function() {}` and `=>` is in the `this` context and how the invocation affects `this`.

In `function() {}` `this` is determined by the way function is invoked. If invoking it as a method on the object, `this` will be the object itself: `actions.updateCVId()`.
I call it `soft linked this`.

In an arrow function case `=>` `this` is automatically bound to `this` of the lexical scope where the function is defined. In your example it's an `undefined`, which is default case for `'strict mode'`.
No matter how the arrow function is invoked later, it will have `this` as `undefined`.
I call it `hard linked this`.

You can find more details about `this` keyword in [this article](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/).